# How to query multiple products with different types from Google Play Billing 5?

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I upgraded to Google Play Billing 5 in the hopes that I could use the new `queryProductDetailsAsync` method to query a list of products with differing BillingClient.ProductType types. I saw nothing in the documentation against doing this.

However, once I tried with multiple product types I received error message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All products should be of the same product type.` from `com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams$Builder.setProductList`.

**Is there any way to achieve this or will I have to make 2 separate calls, one for subs type and one for inapp type? How have others navigated the case of displaying multiple product types on one page?**

Sample Code:

I tried querying for 2 products at a time,

```
val productList = mutableListOf(
QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
  .setProductId(sku1)
  .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
  .build(),

QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
  .setProductId(sku2)
  .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
  .build()
)

QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList).build()
```

This gives:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All products should be of the same product type.`

Answer (score 0):

You have already guessed it correct, you have to make multiple calls to get the Subs and InApp details. Both can't be clubbed into single request.

Question - **How have others navigated the case of displaying multiple product types on one page?**
Ans - For Example, query InApp & Subs Detail call parallelly and then combine the result of both and display in the UI.